# What's the difference between "next start" and "node server.js"?

Tags: next.js

So I'm struggling a bit with this. Let's say I build my NextJS project, I have 2 css files one of them is 10mb. Then I run `next start` and I see on Lighthouse that the file size is only a few kb. But if I run `node server.js` on the standalone folder, the css file size stays the same and that's a problem. Is this the intended behavior? Is there any way to fix this?

When I say standalone folder I mean this: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing#automatically-copying-traced-files-experimental

Comment: Build the app with ‘next build’ first before you run the server file

Comment: That's what I did. What I want to know is the difference between `next start` and running `node server.js` on the "standalone" folder regarding the CSS optimizations.

Comment: [Well for one thing, using the start command doesn’t let you use an Env file for the port](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

I think you're trying to build custom server (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

According to that document, they mention this part which may be related to what you're looking for

> Before deciding to use a custom server, please keep in mind that it
> should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet
> your app requirements. A custom server will remove important
> performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic
> Static Optimization.

**OLD ANSWER**

`next start` usually goes along with `next build` (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production) and it has its own custom configs under `next.config` with a ton of good stuff like file compression, routings, image optimization, etc. (under the hood, it also uses Webpack and Babel for builds)

`node server.js` is just simply to run a server and does nothing else. Therefore, if you want to have better builds like NextJS. You need to add libraries into NodeJS.

You can find some useful libraries here.

https://blog.bitsrc.io/23-insanely-useful-nodejs-libraries-you-should-know-in-2020-5a9b570d5416

Comment: I'm using this (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing#automatically-copying-traced-files-experimental) , so I expected nextjs to do all that stuff by default...seems like I was wrong

Comment: Did you run `next build` initially?

Comment: Yes, `next build` is what generates the "standalone" folder inside the .next folder

Comment: I think you're trying on this https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server? They also mention some optimisation problems if we use a custom server